# How To Re-add An Extension To The VSCode Sidebar/Activity Bar

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I accidentally removed the MongoDB extension from my sidebar/activity bar in VSCode while adjusting my layout. When I initially installed the extension, It automatically put a MongoDB icon on the sidebar which was convenient.

I tried restarting VSCode, dragging and dropping from the extensions panel, reinstalling the extension, going through all VSCode settings, googling, and SO'ing, but I couldn't find any solution.

If there's no answer, I might just have to try uninstalling VSCode and reinstalling everything again.

[image: Docker extension available on sidebar]

Comment: Try the `View: Reset View Locations` command from the Command Palette.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, if you have moved views around and get messed up, try the

`View: Reset View Locations` command from the Command Palette.

It will reset *all* your views but you will have at least refound or relocated any missing views.

Also, if you can't find a view it was probably inside another view - not just in a view container like the Side Bar or Panel at the top level, but within one of the other views within one of the main view containers.

Answer (score 11):

To add an icon that was available from an extension, you can follow the steps below.

1. Right-click on of the icons on the sidebar/activity bar.
2. Recheck whichever icon you're missing.
3. The icon should appear.

---

If you want to reset all of your icons, then follow the steps below.

1. Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>.
2. Search for *View: Reset View Locations*
3. All of your icons should be reset to default.

---

You can also hide icons a similar way.

1. Right click on the icon you want to remove.
2. Check the *Hide* checkbox.
3. The icon should disappear.

Comment: Your first section to this answer does not work in the situation that I found myself in. I had tried that, but it still didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to trust the workspace; otherwise, it will not show icons of extensions in the activity bar.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).